# Generic parameter delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, covariance, variance

I'm a bit fuzzy on the new Action/Func/Variance/CoVariance stuff, which is probably what I need.

What I want is to be able to pass a delegate as a parameter to a method, that takes a string and returns a bool. The problem is that I can't use a typed delegate or interface since it will be used in different libraries which doesn't share libraries, and both will be invoked by a third.

So in general I want the delegate to be inferred by it's input and returning type.

So it'll be like:

```
delegate bool IncludeItemDelegate(string item);

ClassA.FetchItems(int someParameter,includeItemDelegate);
ClassB.FetchItems(int someParameter,string someOtherParam,includeItemDelegate);
```

Where A and B doesnt share any libraries, can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Predicate is built-in and also signals intent:

```
ClassA.FetchItems(int someParameter, Predicate<string> filter);
```

Comment: Yes, this is nicer than Func<string, bool>.

Comment: Ah, a little more esoteric perhaps but seems to fit

Answer (score 7):

How about `Func<string,bool>` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to pass the Predicate as a lambda

```
class A
{
    static public IEnumerable<string> FetchItems(int max, Predicate<string> filter)
    {
        var l = new List<string>() {"test", "fest", "pest", "häst"};
        return l.FindAll(filter).Take(max);
    }
}
```

like this

```
var res = A.FetchItems(2, s => s.EndsWith("est"));
```